# Transposing Sections of Data in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help to 'transpose' several blocks of data to another area of the worksheet on some sort of loop. The data is currently set out as per below:

```
Rob    Dave   John   Peter   Jane   Lily   Mel    Amy
1      4      7      3       2      5      8      6
blue   green  brown  black   purple orange yellow white
apple  pear   grape  lemon   banana kiwi   mango  strawberry
```

I was wondering if anyone might know some relevant VBA code that might let me transform it into the following:

```
Rob    Dave   John   Peter
1      4      7      3
blue   green  brown  black
apple  pear   grape  lemon
Jane   Lily   Mel    Amy
2      5      8      6
purple orange yellow white
banana kiwi   mango  strawberry
```

This is just two groups of horizontally arranged data that I want to shift into vertical blocks. The actual workbook contains many more blocks of data so may require some sort of loop. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your data set always even and contain 4 rows?

Comment: Hi Kory. Yes, it's always 4 columns wide (with about 200 blocks of 4 columns running horizontally across the sheet). The number of rows is constant too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the variable **nBlocks** to the total number of *4 X 4* blocks you have and run:

```
Sub BlockMover()
    Dim nBlocks As Long, N As Long, i As Long
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    nBlocks = 3
    For i = 2 To nBlocks
        N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set r1 = Range(Cells(1, 4 * (i - 1) + 1), Cells(4, 4 * (i - 1) + 4))
        Set r2 = Range("A" & N)
        r1.Copy r2
        r1.Clear
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student. This works pretty much how I need it to. The only issue I have is that the blocks of data being moved contain cell references (relative not absolute) to a raw data sheet. When the above repositions the blocks, the relative references point to the wrong information in the raw data sheet. Is there a simple way to convert all these cell references to absolute before the above macro rearranges the blocks?

Comment: I've found a workaround. I've amended the 'r1.Copy r2' line to 'r1.Cut r2' and then deleted the 'r1.Clear' line. Seems to do the trick. I've noticed in the past that if you cut (rather than copy) a cell to a different area of the sheet, it retains the absolute reference. Appreciate your help with this and your quick response. You've saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score -1):

I would use the built in function [Transpose()](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/TRANSPOSE-function-6910a6ed-b6bc-4671-8447-0b1a65dffde8).